# Show messages in systemctl status output when using PAMName

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to create a systemd service that spins up a session for a user and runs a command inside of it. It uses PAMName to spin up the appropriate session, as so:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service instance for %I
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%I
Environment=XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
PAMName=my-service
# Use basic echo for testing unit functionality.
ExecStart=/bin/echo Test output
StandardOutput=journal
# Use same fd as stdout
StandardError=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The issue I'm running into is that none of the output shows up in the output of `systemctl status`. It *does* show up in `journalctl -e`, so it is getting logged, just not associated with the unit. The documentation for PAMName says:

> Note that when this option is used for a unit it is very likely (depending on PAM configuration) that the main unit process will be migrated to its own session scope unit when it is activated. This process will hence be associated with two units: the unit it was originally started from (and for which PAMName= was configured), and the session scope unit. Any child processes of that process will however be associated with the session scope unit only.

I was hoping the dual association would result in output from the main process, at least, showing up in the `systemctl status`, even if output from child processes didn't, but it appears no output does at all. This makes it tricky to see what when wrong when there's an error starting the service, or to look at past logs for the service.

Is there any way to get log messages to show up as associated with service unit (whether via stdout or via some other logging mechanism) when using PAMName?